# iOS: Moving instance of AVAudioPlayer from one variable to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Here's what I'm looking to do:  I have an AVAudioPlayer called `primaryPlayer` playing a track, and I want it to continue uninterrupted while I transfer the player to `secondaryPlayer`.  I'll then be using the `primaryPlayer` for a new AVAudioPlayer instance to play alongside the original track.

Maybe it's as simple as this:

```
secondaryPlayer=primaryPlayer;
primaryPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:songURL error:nil];
```

**these two variables are properties of the class, hence their lack of definition.*

I'm worried that I may be missing something.  For instance, does this code just set the two variables to point to the same memory address?  So that after the second line of code, both variables correspond to the same player?

I think this may be more of an Objective C (or maybe just C) question than anything else, but thanks for reading and any "pointers" on this would be terrific! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `primaryPlayer` player points to a valid `AVAudioPlayer` instance at address `0x1234` and `secondaryPlayer` has an arbitrary value and that both are declared as `strong` properties.

```
secondaryPlayer=primaryPlayer;
```

Now both variables point to the same object (at address `0x1234`).

```
primaryPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:songURL error:nil];
```

`secondary` player still points to the same object and being a strong reference, that object is still alive. `primaryPlayer` now points to the newly created object, so now you have two different player objects.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation.  Would the behaviour I was concerned about (basically, that the two variables would end up being the same thing) have happened if the command &secondaryPlayer=&primaryPlayer had been used?  Just trying to better understand these pointers!

Comment: No, that wouldn't compile, because `&secondaryPlayer` is not assignable.